Embeddings of pseudo metric spaces into seminormed Spaces
There is a theorem stating that every metric space embeds isometrically into $\ell _{\infty}$.
My question: is there a generalized result for pseudo metric spaces embedding isometrically into semi-normed spaces? Is/would this result be interesting/useful?
Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question.

It is definitely not the case that every metric space embeds into $\ell^\infty$ by cardinality reasons, there must be some size assumption on the spaces

@AlessandroCodenotti certainly OP means $\ell^\infty$ of some set (possibly not countable).

Would you say what is meant by "pseudo"? Allows zero distance? negative distance? If it just relaxes to allow distance zero, I guess one can get results as trivial corollaries of the metric case.

@YCor there are metric spaces of arbitrarily large cardinality, $\ell^\infty$ of no set is going to be big enough. I suppose there is a "separable" missing in front of metric spaces. Or is the theorem that for every metric space $X$ there exists a set $Y$ such that $X$ embeds isometrically into $\ell^\infty(Y)$?

@AlessandroCodenotti I’m pretty sure YCor meant that the index set $Y$ of $\ell_\infty(Y)$ can depend on $X$, so the second one.

@DavidGao Yes, exactly. Fix $x_0\in X$, and $Y$ a dense subset of $X$, and take the map $x\mapsto f_x\in\ell^\infty(Y)$, where $f_x(y)=d(y,x)-d(y,x_0)$.

An interesting/useful generalization: Every uniform space (i.e. a space with a structure defined by a set of pseudometrics) embeds, as a closed uniform subspace, into a locally convex space (i.e. a space with a structure defined by a set of seminorms): Arens and Eells, Pacific J. Math. 6 (1956), 397--403.

Yes. If $(X, d)$ is a pseudometric space, then we may may define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ by $x \sim y$ iff $d(x, y) = 0$. Then $(X/{\sim}, d’)$ with $d’([x], [y]) = d(x, y)$ is a metric space, so there is some isometric embedding $\phi: X/{\sim} \to \ell_\infty(I)$. Now, let $\kappa = \sup_{x \in X} |[x]|$ and pick a vector space $V$ of cardinality at least $\kappa$ (say, $V = \mathbb{K}[\kappa]$). For each equivalence class $[x]$, fix an injection $\psi_{[x]}: [x] \to V$. Now, equip $\ell_\infty(I) \times V$ with the seminorm:
$$p(f, v) = \|f\|_{\ell_\infty(I)}$$
Then $\pi: X \to (\ell_\infty(I) \times V, p)$ defined by,
$$\pi(x) = (\phi([x]), \psi_{[x]}(x))$$
is an isometric embedding. (I don’t see how such a result is in any way interesting or useful though.)
